# Excel VBA to Office Script

Tags: excel, typescript, vba, office365, office-scripts

I am suffering with making an Office Script code from a VBA code. ChatGPT cannot help and sadly i did not learn any JS or any script language. Could you help me please with transforming this VBA code to Office Script?

Basically this code copy the rows that contains "Lejárt" data in the G column and paste it to an other Worksheet.

This is the VBA code (FYI: `Munka1` means `Sheet1`):

```
    Sub masolas()
    
    a = Worksheets("Munka1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 2 To a
        If Worksheets("Munka1").Cells(i, 7).Value = "Lejárt" Then
        
            Worksheets("Munka1").Rows(i).Copy
            Worksheets("Munka2").Activate
            b = Worksheets("Munka2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Worksheets("Munka2").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Worksheets("Munka1").Activate
    
        End If
    Next
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Munka1").Cells(1, 1).Select
    End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried asking Copilot? https://copilot.microsoft.com/

Answer (score 1):

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [getRangeEdge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.range?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&view=excel-js-preview#excel-excel-range-getrangeedge-member(1))

> [copyFrom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.range?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&view=excel-js-preview#excel-excel-range-copyfrom-member(1))

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let sheet1 = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1");
    let sheet2 = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet2");
    //  Clear Sheet2 if needed
    // sheet2.getRange().clear(ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.contents);
    let lastRow = sheet1.getRange("A:A").getLastCell().getRangeEdge(ExcelScript.KeyboardDirection.up).getRowIndex();
    let values = sheet1.getRange("G1:G" + (lastRow + 1)).getValues();
    for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if (values[i][0] == "Lejárt") {
            let lastRow2 = sheet2.getRange("A:A").getLastCell().getRangeEdge(ExcelScript.KeyboardDirection.up).getRowIndex();
            if (sheet2.getCell(lastRow2, 0).getText()) {
                lastRow2 += 1;
            }
            sheet2.getCell(lastRow2, 0).copyFrom(sheet1.getRange(`${i + 1}:${i + 1}`), ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.all, false, false);
        }
    }
}
```